# Does the Java compiler optimization a method called once by removing the method?

Tags: java, javac, compiler-optimization

Would the java compiler (any mainstream compiler) take something like

```
void foo () {
    int x = 1;
    System.out.println(x);
}

void bar() {
    foo()
}
```

and optimize the foo method away if it is only called in bar resulting in bytecode that would also be generated by this:

```
void bar() {
    int x = 1;
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

Comment: Most likely not since java compilers don't really optimize. They leave that to the JVM

Comment: It had better not. `foo` is visible outside the class it is defined in. Maybe if `foo` were private.

Comment: similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7772864/would-java-inline-methods-during-optimization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it doesn't.  Javac doesn't do much optimization beyond constant folding.  In java the optimization happens at runtime with the JIT.

I created a short example to show how the method did not get inlined in the bytecode even though it was only called once.  Private and public make no difference.

```
Compiled from "Test.java"
public class Test {
  public Test();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       3: ldc           #3                  // String Hello before method
       5: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
       8: invokestatic  #5                  // Method publicMethod:()V
      11: invokestatic  #6                  // Method privateMethod:()V
      14: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      17: ldc           #7                  // String Hello after method
      19: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      22: return

  public static void publicMethod();
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       3: ldc           #8                  // String The public method
       5: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
       8: return

  private static void privateMethod();
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       3: ldc           #9                  // String The private method
       5: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
       8: return
}
```

Comment: That means that if it crashes, the stacktrace is the optimised version usually, because it gets optimised on runtime?